# 2023-08-20 13:33:45.958 osascript[28784:1276488] CFURLGetFSRef was passed a URL which has no scheme (the URL will not work with other CFURL routines)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am writing a simple program on Mac in `python3 (PyCharm)` that sends a WhatsApp message with an attachment using `pywhatkit`.
When I run the program from Pycharm it works alright.

However when I try to run it from Terminal

```
%    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3   /Users/me/Desktop/pythonProject2/main.py
```

I get the following error message:

> 2023-08-20 13:33:45.958 osascript[28784:1276488] CFURLGetFSRef was
> passed a URL which has no scheme (the URL will not work with other
> CFURL routines)

I am testing running it from terminal because eventually the idea is to use AppleScript to run it from an excel spreadsheet on VBA

I found some mentions of this problem in previous posts but none of the propesed solutions seemed relevant to me.
I am fairly new to python programming (or coding in general) so please bear with me.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated

`MAc OS Monterey 12.4`

`Python 3.11`

Code: pythonProject2 contains the following four modules:

module convertpdf.py

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pdf_path = "/Users/me/Library/Group     Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/RDBMailTempFolder/Daily Drinkback   Report.pdf"


def convert_pdf():
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)

    for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].save('page' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

module getexceldata.py

```
import xlwings as xw


excel_file = ("/Users/me/Library/Mobile    Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MMM/MMM_satin/Drinkback   Report_2023.xlsm")

def get_excel_data():
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
    active_sheet_name = wb.sheets.active.name
    active_sheet = wb.sheets[active_sheet_name]
    return active_sheet
```

module sendwp.py

```
import pywhatkit as pwk
from getexceldata import get_excel_data
from convertpdf import convert_pdf

def send_wp():
    name = get_excel_data().range("name_daily").value
    phone = get_excel_data().range("Phone_daily").value
    convert_pdf()
    img_path = "page0.jpg"
    caption = f"Hi there {name}, This is your daily drinkback    report. Please double check all entries"

    # pwk.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+xxxxxxxx", "hello", 15)
    pwk.sendwhats_image(phone, img_path, caption, 15)
```

module main.py

```
from sendwp  import send_wp

send_wp()
```

Comment: There is very little we can do without seeing your code.  The implication is that you tried to fetch a url like "www.app.com" instead of the correct version "https://www.app.com".

Comment: So, are you not yet using osascript to launch this?  That's an osascript error, but I don't see any osascript commands.  If you just say `python3 main.py`, does it run?

Comment: I ran 'python3 main.py' with the following result: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/me/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: I am not using osascript. I don't really know what that is, sorry

Comment: I saw that.  I asked you what happens if you just type `python3` without typing the whole path.  Python should be in your PATH.

Comment: typing 'python3' gives the following

Comment: Python 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Honestly.  What I meant was to run YOUR script using just `python` instead of giving the whole path.  `python ~/Desktop/pythonProject2/main.py`.

Comment: figured it out. In module 'sendwp.py' I needed to specify the full path for '"page0.jpg"'. Thanks for having a look